# I don't know if it is native JS or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to web programming and stumbled upon this tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/31/how-to-create-a-simple-multi-item-slider/

My quick question: Is the Javascript used there all native or is it a weird mixture with jQuery?

I already know jQuery but don't know what the "init" and "$el" stuff for example means... Will I be able to understand the whole code when studying native Javascript?

Comment: _"Will I be able to understand the whole code when studying native Javascript?"_ How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: *"A tutorial on how to create a simple category slider with a minimal design using CSS animations and jQuery"* **AND JQUERY**.

Comment: @j08691 with this will to learn? I think no.

Answer (score 3):

Well the fact that "jQuery" is mentioned 6 times on the page you've linked to, I'm going to say yes. Yes it is.

> For today’s tutorial we want to show you ... CSS animations **and some jQuery.**

Not to mention if you click to [view the demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemSlider/), then view the page's source you'll find:

```
<script src=".../jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're wanting to learn jQuery, check out http://try.jquery.com and http://learn.jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

the $ sign is used to reference JQuery
and init, well thats a function name. Given that you say you know JQuery and you ask this question i would recommend checking tutorials on JQuery and JavaScript and become familiar with both syntax

Comment: Just seeing `$` doesn't guarantee jQuery.

Comment: a well thats true but usually when u denote $ before ( ), but yes your very much right, the real identifier is actually seeing the link to JQuery itself